# Are there any CDNs that give you full control over HTTP headers?

Tags: http, cdn

Are any CDNs (Content Delivery Networks) that provide control and/or customization of all or most HTTP headers?

Specifically, I'm interested in controlling the Expires, ETag, and Cache-Control headers, although other headers interest me as well.

I understand that part of the value proposition of CDNs is that they "just work" and set these headers to somewhat optimal values (for most use cases), but I am definitely interested in controlling these headers myself.

Answer (score 1):

Akamai has a full interface for allowing this type of control on a per-property, per-header basis.  It is a standard XML based config file.  You can set each header to be a specific value, respect the headers passed through, add if not present, have exceptions based on User Agent etc.

Essentially, within reason, it is completely configurable.  I have found setting defaults when absent but allowing applications/admins to set their own values is generally the best approach but it really does depend on the quality and understanding of the developer/admin.

Like most CDN providers Akamai have some default behaviors baked in, but the values are completely configurable.  It has been a couple of years since I actively managed a CDN, but at the time Limelight was working on being feature compatible with Akamai and was most of the way there, so I would expect that they have similar functionality now.

In general, most CDN vendors will strive for feature compatibility with the big player in the market and Akamai is definitely it for CDN.

Comment: I was under the impression that Akamai does not deal directly with "little fish" (e.g. me), and you can only sign-up through re-sellers that have their own management interfaces (that don't necessarily support all Akamai features). Is this not the case?

Comment: You are probably right on that front - I was dealing with Akamai as part of a large account, so I had all options available to me.  In my experience though, even the smaller scale providers will respect your cache control headers as long as they are not too short (Amazon Cloudfront, for example defaults to 1 day but you can set expiry as short as 1 hour).

Comment: If you have no access to the setting of the headers on the server/application side, then you will have more trouble.  When I have had issues with that type of behavior (hard coded headers from a content layer etc.) I have used something like a load balancer (Netscaler, F5 etc.) to manipulate the headers as needed on the way through....